# How could I give KVM more hard disk space

Tags: virtual-machines

I want to use kvm as virtualisation software, but it is difficult. Is says that I dont have space on the node, that is not true.

How could I solve this big problem? http://prntscr.com/2rlcq1

Answer (score 3):

You have most likely run out, or nearly so, of space in the filesystem where your KVM images are kept. This can vary by distribution, but in my experience is often somewhere in `/var`. Simply add more space to that filesystem and you should be okay.

Comment: I have 2TB disk space, how can I give that to KVM?

Comment: Simply add more space to the filesystem where your KVM images are kept.